# Visual studio intellisense not recognizing symbols after dependency recompile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, intellisense

I've got a c++ cli project A and a C# project B. Project B depends on project A.
Everything works fine, until I recompile project A. After that the visual studio intellisense does not recognize any of the symbols from project A that are referred to inside project B. My screen is filled with red stripes and I can't do any decent programming.

My current workaround is to restart VS every time this happens, but this really slows down my programming work.

Is there a way to solve this problem or is there a faster workaround?

Comment: Hard to guess, this never goes wrong when I do this.  But I always use a project reference when the C++/CLI project is still unstable and always build the solution instead of just the project.  Which I suppose is the workaround.

Comment: I too use a normal project reference and build the entire solution; it doesn't make a difference.